# Generating data from meshgrid data (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to ask how to generate corresponding values from a meshgrid. I have a function "foo" that takes one 1D array with the length of 2, and returns some real number.

```
import numpy as np

def foo(X):  
    #this function takes a vector, e.g., np.array([2,3]), and returns a real number.
    return sum(X)**np.sin( sum(X) );

x = np.arange(-2, 1, 1)          # points in the x axis
y = np.arange( 3, 8, 1)          # points in the y axis
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)         # X, Y : grid
```

I generate X and Y grids using meshgrid.

Then, how can I generate corresponding Z values using "foo" function, in order to plot them in 3D, e.g., plotting using plot_surface function with X,Y,Z values?

Here the question is how to generate Z values, which has the same shape to X and Y, using "foo" function. Since my "foo" function only takes an 1D array, I do not know how I can uses this function with X and Y to generate corresponding Z values.

Comment: Do you want `z = foo([x, y])` for each point `(x, y)` in the meshgrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack your two numpy arrays in "depth" using [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), and then modify your `foo` function, so that it operates on only the last axis of your stacked array. This is easily done using [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) with parameter `axis=-1`, instead of using the builtin `sum`:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(xy):
    return np.sum(xy, axis=-1) ** np.sin(np.sum(xy, axis=-1))

x = np.arange(-2, 1, 1)          # points in the x axis
y = np.arange( 3, 8, 1)          # points in the y axis
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)         # X, Y : grid
XY = np.dstack((X, Y))
```

And now, you should get:

```
>>> XY.shape
(5, 3, 2)
>>> foo(XY)
array([[ 1.        ,  1.87813065,  1.1677002 ],
       [ 1.87813065,  1.1677002 ,  0.35023496],
       [ 1.1677002 ,  0.35023496,  0.2136686 ],
       [ 0.35023496,  0.2136686 ,  0.60613935],
       [ 0.2136686 ,  0.60613935,  3.59102217]])
```

---

If you want to achieve the same effect, but *without* modifying `foo`, then you can use [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), which should do exactly what you need:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(foo, -1, XY)
array([[ 1.        ,  1.87813065,  1.1677002 ],
       [ 1.87813065,  1.1677002 ,  0.35023496],
       [ 1.1677002 ,  0.35023496,  0.2136686 ],
       [ 0.35023496,  0.2136686 ,  0.60613935],
       [ 0.2136686 ,  0.60613935,  3.59102217]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful solution. This is exactly what I wanted to do. However, I have some problems to apply this approach to my code bock. I actually posted another question regarding this matter [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715227/making-a-function-that-can-take-arguments-in-various-shapes). My actual foo function is actually something like `return X[0] + X[1];`, so it cannot perform an iterative operation on a nested array, and can only take the shape of (2,). Thus, if I put XY into my actual foo function, it spits our error. In this case, how can generate Z as you did?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot it!

Comment: By the way, can you let me know how I should change your ode if I just want to use my current foo function, which can only take (2,) shape?

Comment: @AnnDescomp I've posted an answer on your other question. See if that works for you...

Comment: I am now looking at "..." indexing. In addition, I'd want to know if there is a way to generate Z with my current foo function, which can explicitly take only one (2,) shape Numpy array as an argument.

Comment: @AnnDescomp You _don't_ want to modify your foo function, but you still want to achieve the same result?

Comment: @AnnDescomp See the edit I've made to my answer. Hopefully that should solve your issue. Again, don't forget to upvote! :-)