# making a function that can take arguments in various shapes

Tags: python, numpy

Q1)
Numpy functions can take arguments in different shapes. For instance, np.sum(V) can take either of two below and return outputs with different shapes.

```
x1= np.array( [1,3] ) #(1)
x2= np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]) #(2)
```

I am making my own function something like below, which adds two values in an 1D vector with the length of two and return the real number.

```
def foo(V):
    return V[0]+V[1];
```

However, this foo function can only take one 1D vector and cannot take any other shapes. It can only take x1 above as an argument but not x2. If I want to make my function work with either of two variables above(x1 and x2), or with any other shapes that has arrays with the length of 2 in their last dimension, how should I revise my foo function?

---

---------------------------update------------------------------

My original function was a hardcoded negative gaussian pdf function.

```
def nGauss(X, mu, cov):
    # multivariate negative gaussian.    
    # mu is a vector and cov is a covariance matrix.

    k = X.shape[0];
    dev = X-mu
    p1 = np.power( np.power(np.pi * 2, k) , -0.5);
    p2 = np.power( np.linalg.det(cov)  , -0.5)
    p3 = np.exp( -0.5 * np.dot( np.dot(dev.transpose(), np.linalg.inv(cov)), dev));

    return -1.0 * p1 * p2 * p3;
```

Now his function can return only one pdf value. For example, it can only take arguments like np.array([1,2]), but cannot take arguments X like np.array([[[1,2], [5,6]], [[7,8],[9,0]]]). Here my question was how to make my gaussian function takes arguments of arbitrary shapes and return the pdf value of each point maintaining the same structure except the last dimension, such as
`nGauss(np.array( [1,2] ), mu, cov)` returns [ 0.000023 ], and 
`nGauss(np.array([[[1,2], [5,6]], [[7,8],[9,0]]]), mu, cov)` returns [[ 0.000023, 0000014], [0.000012, 0.000042]].

I notice that scipy function 'multivariate_normal.pdf' can do this.

---

Q2)
I am also having a difficulty in understanding np's basic array.

```
t1=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
t2=np.array([1,2,3])
t3=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6],5])
```

The shape of t1 is (2,3), and it seems legitimate in terms of matrix perspective; 2 rows and 3 columns. However, the shape of t2 is (3,), which I think has to be (3). What's the meaning of the empty space after "3,"? Also, the shape of t3 is (3,). In this case, is the meaning of the empty space that dimensions vary?

In advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want the shape of the output of foo to be, for the case of `x1` and for the case of `x2`? I'm guessing scalar for #(1) and (2, 2) for #(2)? But you're adding the innermost dimensions again? It would be helpful if you could post the desired output by calculating manually by hand.

Comment: @Praveen I updated my original gaussian function. Now it can only take one vector as an argument X. So, if I put `np.array( [1,2] )` as X, it will give me a pdf value at that point. I now wonder if I can make my gaussian function to accept any shapes of data and return the pdf values in the same structure to the X arguments except the last dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, I'm guessing you want to add the innermost dimensions of your arrays, regardless of how many dimensions the arrays have. The simplest way to do this is to use [ellipsis indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing). Here's a detailed example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(24).reshape((3, 4, 2))
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
>>> a[..., 0]
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
>>> a[..., 1]
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7],
       [ 9, 11, 13, 15],
       [17, 19, 21, 23]])
>>> a[..., 0] + a[..., 1]
array([[ 1,  5,  9, 13],
       [17, 21, 25, 29],
       [33, 37, 41, 45]])
```

This works equally well for a 1D array:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> a[..., 0] + a[..., 1]
3
```

So just define `foo` as:

```
def foo(V):
    return V[..., 0] + V[..., 1]
```

---

For your `nGauss` function, the simplest solution is to use [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). For example, you would call it like this:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(nGauss, -1, x1, mu, cov)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! "..." indexing is new to me, so I will look into it with your detailed example. Regarding Q2, am I thinking it in a wrong way?

Comment: @AnnDescomp I'll add an answer for Q2 in a bit, but meanwhile, take a look at hpualj's answer too. That describes Q2 in good detail, and provides some nice links as well.

Comment: thanks, now I am looking into his links. I also update the first question with my original function. It seems that my fake foo function was not a good substitution to my original Gaussian function. Any additional input will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your function works with both arrays:

```
In [1]: def foo(V):
   ...:     return V[0]+V[1]
   ...: 
In [2]: foo(np.array([1,3]))
Out[2]: 4
In [3]: foo(np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]))
Out[3]: 
array([[ 6,  8],
       [10, 12]])
```

This answer is just the sum of these two arrays:

```
In [4]: np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])[0]
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [5]: np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])[1]
Out[5]: 
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

If you expected something else, you'll have to show us.

As for your second question:

```
In [6]: t1=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
   ...: t2=np.array([1,2,3])
   ...: t3=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6],5])
   ...: 
In [7]: t1.shape
Out[7]: (2, 3)
In [8]: t2.shape
Out[8]: (3,)
In [9]: t3.shape
Out[9]: (3,)
```

`(3,)` is a 1 element tuple. Compare these expressions.

```
In [11]: (3)
Out[11]: 3
In [12]: (3,)
Out[12]: (3,)
```

There have been several recent questions about (3,) v (3,1) shape arrays, and `np.array([[1,2,3]])` v. `np.array([1,2,3])`.

`t3` is an object dtype array, with 3 elements.  The 3 inputs are different length, so it can't create a 2d array.  Stay away from this type of array for now.  Focus on the simpler arrays.

```
In [10]: t3
Out[10]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 5], dtype=object)
In [13]: t3[0]
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]
In [14]: t3[2]
Out[14]: 5
```

[Numpy: Why is difference of a (2,1) array and a vertical matrix slice not a (2,1) array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706277/numpy-why-is-difference-of-a-2-1-array-and-a-vertical-matrix-slice-not-a-2-1)

[Difference between single and double bracket Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694318/difference-between-single-and-double-bracket-numpy-array)

=====================

With the `nGauss`:

```
In [53]: mu=np.array([0,0])
In [54]: cov=np.eye(2)
In [55]: xx=np.array([[[1,2], [5,6]], [[7,8],[9,0]]])
In [56]: np.apply_along_axis(nGauss, -1, xx, mu, cov)
Out[56]: 
array([[ -1.30642333e-02,  -9.03313360e-15],
       [ -4.61510838e-26,  -4.10103631e-19]])
```

`apply_along_axis` iterates on the 1st 2 dim, passing each `xx[i,j,:]` to `nGauss`.  It's not fast, but is relatively easy to apply.

```
k = X.shape[0];  # I assume you want
k = X.shape[[1]   # the last dimension
dev = X-mu     # works as long as mu has k terms
```

this is a scalar:

```
p1 = np.power( np.power(np.pi * 2, k) , -0.5);
```

so is

```
p2 = np.power( np.linalg.det(cov)  , -0.5)
```

So it comes down to generalizing this expression:

```
p3 = np.exp( -0.5 * np.dot( np.dot(dev.transpose(), np.linalg.inv(cov)), dev));
```

In the simple (2,) `x` case, `dev` is 1d, and `dev.transpose()` does nothing.

It's easier to generalize `einsum` than `dot`; I think the equivalent is:

```
p3 = np.einsum('j,j', np.einsum('i,ij', dev, np.linalg.inv(cov)), dev)
p3 = np.exp( -0.5 * p3)
```

which simplifies to

```
p3 = np.einsum('i,ij,j', dev, np.linalg.inv(cov), dev)
```

generalizing to higher dim:

```
p3 = np.einsum('...i,ij,...j', dev, np.linalg.inv(cov), dev)
```

So with:

```
def nGaussA(X, mu, cov):
    # multivariate negative gaussian.    
    # mu is a vector and cov is a covariance matrix.

    k = X.shape[-1];
    dev = X-mu
    p1 = np.power( np.power(np.pi * 2, k) , -0.5);
    p2 = np.power( np.linalg.det(cov)  , -0.5)
    p3 = np.einsum('...i,ij,...j', dev, np.linalg.inv(cov), dev)
    p3 = np.exp( -0.5 * p3)
    return -1.0 * p1 * p2 * p3;
```

matching earlier values:

```
In [85]: nGaussA(x,mu,cov)
Out[85]: -0.013064233284684921
In [86]: nGaussA(xx,mu,cov)
Out[86]: 
array([[ -1.30642333e-02,  -9.03313360e-15],
       [ -4.61510838e-26,  -4.10103631e-19]])
```

So the way to generalize the function is to check each step.  If it produces a scalar, keep it.  If operates with an `x` keep it.  But if it requires coordinating dimensions with other arrays, use a numpy operation that does that.  Often that involves broadcasting.  Sometimes it helps to study other numpy functions to see how they generalize (e.g. `apply_along_axis`, `apply_over_axes`, `cross`, etc).

An interactive numpy session is essential; allowing me to try ideas with small sample arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It really helps me understand mysterious arrays. Meanwhile, now I realize that I should have posted my original function, which I just updated. I wrote a negative gaussian pdf function, which takes one np.array in (n,) shape. Thus, it can only take arguments like np.array([1,2]), but cannot take arguments like np.array([[[1,2], [5,6]], [7,8],[9,0]]]). Here my question was how to make my gaussian functions take arguments of arbitrary shapes and return the pdf value of each point maintaining the same structure.

Comment: I've worked out a generalization of your `nGauss`, using `einsum` to generalize your two `dot` products.

Answer (score 1):

for Q1 you can pack and unpack arguments:

```
def foo(*args):

    result = []
    for v in args:
        result.append(v[0] + v[1])

    return result
```

This will allow you pass in as many vector arguments as you want, then iterate over them, returning a list of each result. You can also pack and unpack kwargs with **. More info here:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: The OP wants to use numpy arrays. You can't unpack numpy arrays. If you convert the outermost array into a list and then pass it to the function, you typically lose most of the benefit numpy has to offer in terms of vectorized operations.

Comment: @ZzCalvinzZ Thanks for our inputs!